# Arithmetic Overflow Error

Tags: hardhat, solidity-0.8.x, overflow

We're forking and updating sushiswap contracts. Right now, I'm trying to correct an overflow arithmetic error in the Masterchef Contract. We have tried using an `uncheck{...}` in the following function but got the same error.

Here is a link t the gist

https://gist.github.com/pynchmeister/67120b5fdbf8d00b06d67f90fdba0c98

https://gist.github.com/pynchmeister/daaee8d1d6794946ee2f3abc5a0a4071

```
function updatePool(uint256 _pid) public {
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];
        if (block.number <= pool.lastRewardBlock) {
            return;
        }
        uint256 lpSupply = pool.lpToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        if (lpSupply == 0) {
            pool.lastRewardBlock = block.number;
            unchecked {return;}
        }
        uint256 multiplier = getMultiplier(pool.lastRewardBlock, block.number);
        uint256 gzapReward =
            multiplier*(gzapPerBlock)*(pool.allocPoint)/(
                totalAllocPoint
            );
        gzap.mint(devaddr, gzapReward/(10));
        gzap.mint(address(this), gzapReward);
        pool.accGZapPerShare = pool.accGZapPerShare+(
            gzapReward*(1e12)/(lpSupply)
        );
        pool.lastRewardBlock = block.number;
    }
```

Error:

```
 ZapDirector
       With ERC/LP token added to the field
         should give out GZAPs only after farming time:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 0x11 (Arithmetic operation underflowed or overflowed outside of an unchecked block)
      at ZapDirector.updatePool (contracts/ZapDirector.sol:221)
      at ZapDirector.deposit (contracts/ZapDirector.sol:236)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
      at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1602:23)
      at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:435:16)
      at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1494:18)
```

Comment: Not possible to help, I have no clue of what are half of the variables here.

I'm pretty sure that your issue is one that part:

        `uint256 gzapReward = multiplier*(gzapPerBlock)*(pool.allocPoint)/(totalAllocPoint);`
or 

`pool.accGZapPerShare = pool.accGZapPerShare+(gzapReward*(1e12)/(lpSupply));
`

Comment: might want to double check if there are multiple place overflow/underflow that you didn't wrap.  And you should wrap the calculation , not the result
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/control-structures.html#checked-or-unchecked-arithmetic